# How can I get my PHP code working inside img src in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, src

I've been trying to get a small image of an icon inside of my article thumbnail custom fields in Wordpress website. But the image itself isn't loading but the site understands that image is supposed to be there.

This is my PHP code right now

```
<?php 
$filepath= "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/downarrow.png";
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Magamistuba', true ); 
            if  (!empty( $meta_value )) {echo   '<img src="'.$filepath.'">'.$meta_value;}
            else {} 

?>
```

On this picture it shows how it appears in the console.
[image]

Here is how it is when i tryed

```
$filepath = bloginfo('template_url') ."/img/downarrow.png";
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why did you add the **literal string** `<?php bloginfo....` to the filepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.

```
$filepath = get_template_directory_uri()."/img/downarrow.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$filepath= bloginfo('template_url') ."/img/downarrow.png";
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Magamistuba', true ); 
            if  (!empty( $meta_value )) {echo   '<img src="'.$filepath.'">'.$meta_value;}
            else {}
```

You are already in PHP mode, so this is how you write it.

Also, never end a PHP script by closing PHP tags.

Comment: Not working as it's supposed to. Check my answer to @Rounin and edit to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `<?php` a second time.

Instead it is sufficient to write:

```
$filepath = bloginfo('template_url') . '/img/downarrow.png';
```

Comment: I've tryed this before and this doesn't work as it's supposed to. It shows file directory as text and icon thumbnail(not image itself) on my website.

Comment: Sadly, this gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $filepath= bloginfo('template_url') . "/img/downarrow.png";
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Magamistuba', true );
    if  (!empty( $meta_value )) {echo   '<img src="'.$filepath.'">'.$meta_value;}
    else {}
?>
```

Comment: Not working as it's supposed to. Check my answer to @Rounin and edit to the post.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$filepath` is a String and not PHP code.

You must put your code outside the string and [concatenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation).

```php
<?php 
$filepath = bloginfo('template_url') ."/img/downarrow.png";
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Magamistuba', true ); 

if  (!empty( $meta_value )) {
    echo   '<img src="'.$filepath.'">'.$meta_value;
}

?>
```

Comment: Not working as it's supposed to. Check my answer to @Rounin and edit to the post.